# ng repeat in object with dynamic keys

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem writing proper ng-repeat for this object. I would like to display all object properties. There is a main array of apps, each app can have a multiple versions and each version can have multiple users.

Here is object json.

```
"Awesome App 1": {
    "1.16": {
      "Steve": [
        "steve@example.com",
        null
      ],
      "Mike": [
        "mike@example.com",
        null
      ]
    }
  },
  "Awesome App 2": {
    "1.7.0": {
      "steve": [
        "steve@example.com",
        null
      ]
    }
  },
```

...

Problem is that keys are dynamic and I don`t know how to map it in ng-repeat. Thanks for a help.

Comment: What do you want to do with the null value in the array?

Comment: Please give an example of the output you are expecting

Comment: do you mean something like this: https://plnkr.co/edit/3wMdzrtkpShLgl8mu9sN

Comment: @RameezRaja yes, your solution works! Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

https://plnkr.co/edit/3wMdzrtkpShLgl8mu9sN

```
$scope.data.json = {"Awesome App 1":
......
};

    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in data.json">
          App Name: {{key}} <br/>  
          <span ng-repeat="(key2, val2) in val">
             Version: {{key2}} <br/>
             <span ng-repeat="(key3, val3) in val2">
               User: {{key3}} - {{val3[0]}} <br/>
             </span>
          </span>
       </li>
   </ul>
```